# Hide the displayed article in a most viewed/popular sidebar

Tags: views, panels

In an article panel page, i have a sidebar with the Most Viewed articles as per [RAdioactivity](https://www.drupal.org/project/radioactivity) module. If the main article that I am viewing is one of the Most viewed, I want to hide that article link in the sidebar but instead display the rest of the Most Viewed articles links. How can I do this using Panels, mini Panels, views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by going to **Advanced** > **Contextual Filter**. Choose **Content: Nid**. Then
under "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE", pick "Provide default value", Type = 'Content ID from URL'. Under "**More**", check on 'exclude' checkbox.